# Why Lie algebra (Chevalley–Eilenberg) cohomology are graded Lie algebras but not G-algebras?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

I was reading a paper related to Gerstenhaber algebra structure and came across to this- "Lie algebra (Chevalley–Eilenberg)
cohomology are graded Lie algebras but not G-algebras(Gerstenhaber algebra)".
Can anyone please explain me the reason for the mentioned result?

Comment: It is always difficult to say why somethong does NOT have a property. If you think of Lie cocycles as left invariant differential form this means you should have a naturally defined Lie bracket on l.i. $1$-forms, which is not the case of  a generic Lie group.

Comment: It would be nice if you refer me something to read...

Comment: https://www.emis.de/journals/AM/09-4/roger.pdf